# MongoDB: projection on specific fields of all objects in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB database with following data structure for one Part:
[Part Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODEWT.png)

Now I want to to have a projection on the element `Description`of every object in the array `SensorData`. Using the MonogDB API in .NET with C# my code would look the following:

```
var projection = Builders<Part>.Projection
                .Include(part => part.SensorData[0].Description)
                .Include(part => part.SensorData[1].Description)
                .Include(part => part.SensorData[2].Description)
                //...   
                ;
```

The problem is that the number of objects in `SensorData` is dynamic and may range from 0 to about 20, so including every `Description`field for itself is not possible. The projection has to be done Server-Side as `SensorData -> Values` can be huge.

Is there any Syntax or method to do this kind of projection?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution after asking a colleague: It isn't possible to do this with the `Projection Builder`, but it is with the `aggregation framework`:

```
            var match = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$project",
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"PartData.Description", 1 }
                    }
                }
            };
            var pipeline = new[] { match };
            var aggregationCursor = parts.Aggregate<Part>(pipeline);
            var query = aggregationCursor
                .ToEnumerable()//needed to perform AsQueryable
                .AsQueryable()//Asking for data elements  
            }
```